# $H^1(G, C^\infty(X))$ for homogeneous spaces

Tags: lie-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $X$ a homogeneous space of positive dimension, say $X=G/H$ for a proper subgroup $H$. I'm interested in understanding the group cohomology $H^1(G, C^\infty(X))$, particularly in the case $X=G$, defined as the smooth 1-cocycles $\phi:G\to C^\infty(X)$, modulo coboundaries, with $C^\infty(X)$ considered as a $G$-module.

I currently understand this group mainly in terms of cocycles modulo coboundaries, but I'm missing a good intuitive picture, as well as concrete computational tools.

For example, is it obviously the case that $H^1(G, C^\infty(X))=0$ when $G=X=(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$? For other $X$, it is obviously the case that $H^1(G, C^\infty(X))\neq 0$? This seems to be true from the basic cases I've looked at, in particular $n=1$, but I'm not sure how to approach it in general, or how to fully characterize $H^1$ in these cases.

And are there standard methods for constructing homogeneous spaces with an interesting $H^1$, when $G$ is one of the classical Lie groups? What happens when $G$ is compact and $X=G/T$, where $T$ is a maximal torus?

I do have Knapp's book on cohomology of Lie groups in the mail, but if there are good online references for this kind of thing, they'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I've clarified this a bit in the question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Too bad! I'm also interested in the Lie algebra case, as well as the relationship between the two.

Since so much more seems to be known in the finite-dimensional case, I wonder if it's possible to get some traction by restricting to a class of functions with a Schauder basis.

In fact, I'd be pretty interested in an answer to this question even for finite-dimensional spaces of functions, though I'd then supplement the question by asking how to construct interesting function spaces on e.g. the classical Lie groups.